# C - warning function returns address of local variable -wreturn-local-addr

Tags: c

I wrote a func that gets a line from user.

Running it on windoes doesn't cause any warning.

But on unix i get the warning :

> function UserIO_ReadLineFromUser() returns address of local variable **-wreturn-local-addr**

```
char* UserIO_ReadLineFromUser()
{
int i = 0, lineLen = 0;
char lineFromUser[MAX_INPUT_LINE_LENGTH];
fgets(lineFromUser, MAX_INPUT_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
lineLen = strlen(lineFromUser);
lineFromUser[lineLen-1] = '\0';
while ('\0' != lineFromUser[i])
{
    lineFromUser[i] = tolower(lineFromUser[i]);
    i++;
}
return lineFromUser;
}
```

This is how i call it on main():

```
int main()
{
List* pHead = NULL;
char line[MAX_INPUT_LINE_LENGTH];
while (true)
{
    strcpy(line, UserIO_ReadLineFromUser());
    UserIO_ExecuteLineFromUser(line, &pHead);
}
return 0;
}
```

The program works but i want to get rid of this warning

Comment: The warning you see is most likely not because of `unix vs windows` differences. It is most probably because of the different flags set in the two different compilers you use.

Comment: You are returning a pointer of a local variable from UserIO_ExecuteLineFromUser(). Simple solution: Since you are not using returned value from UserIO_ExecuteLineFromUser(), you can make its return type as void and remove "return lineFromUser;" line from it.

Comment: Assuming you're using gcc, suppress this warning with `-Wno-return-local-addr`: Do not warn about returning a pointer (or in C++, a reference) to a variable that goes out of scope after the function returns.

Comment: I get the error from UserIO_ReadLineFromUser. ill edit the post for it to be more clear

Comment: Also `int main`

Answer (score 3):

You return variable created on stack. This is undefined behavior, cause stack is destroyed after function returns. You should allocate this variable on the heap, or pass to your function memory buffer

Comment: @JoeyMallone that was a misread. It is being used.

Comment: aah! in the first line inside the while block. Yes. Sorry. I missed that too.

Comment: @Alex tnx. so why is it working on windoes? my warning lvl is 4 and i dont get any warnings at visual studio

Comment: its because of compilation warning flags. I am not aware about your windows compiler, but maybe its possible to enable those flags too. Anyway its wrong code, it works cause you don`t use your returning variable

Comment: @Alex I am using the return value. inside strcpy i copy the value returnd into line

Comment: its wrong, it can work for a while, but after changing your code or using another compiler you will get mistakes